# Logging in automatical mode on C++11. Is it real?

Tags: c++, c++11, logging

In debugging purposes I need to know what function was called and when. I can do something like this:

```
std::string getName( unsigned int userId, unsigned char userAge ) {
    Debug::log( getTime() + ": getName( " + intToStr( userId ) ", " + intToStr( userAge ) + " );" );
    // ...
}
```

So I need the whole stack of functions which was called to send it to http server. Debug::log - it's my own log function which have an feature to send the log to a server.

Are there ways to do such loggin in automatical mode? I have many function with various parameters so it's too hard for each function to do something like that. I would prefer something like this:

```
std::string getName( unsigned int userId, unsigned char userAge ) {
    Debug::log( getTime() + ": " + getThisFunctionName( somePointerToThisFunction ) + "( " + dumpFunctionsParameters( somePointerToThisFunction ) + " )" );
    // ...
}
```

Any useful information on this subject would be appreciated!

Comment: C++ is a statically-bound language, with no runtime reflection features. There is no "automatical mode" in C++, as you mean it. You will have to come up with, and devise, your own framework for logging your code. Maybe something macro based. I can think of several possible approaches to generalize declaring class methods, and logging their invocations, but they'll be fairly complicated.

Comment: Well I can write my own template which will use and store the value of `__FUNCTION__` name, but I don't know how to get all the parameters and its values.

Comment: As I said, the C++ is a statically-bound language, with no runtime reflection features. There's no way to "automatically" know the parameters to the current function. Maybe your compiler offers a non-standard extension. Check your compiler's documentation.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I use CLang as compilers so I don't think it offers something useful on this subject :) Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Maybe you are just reinventing a debugger? There is certainly a way to do something crazy like that with LLVM. You might probably also grab the debugging information from the executable. Check GDB's or LLDB's source code. It will take enormous amount of time and effort and will probably still be worse than conventional debugging techniques.

Comment: You may want to look into the -finstrument-functions parameter in gcc/clang, which puts a prefix/suffix function in every function that it is compiled with.